# rollback the transaction when there is an exception in detail with JPA

Tags: jpa, cascade, persist

I am using JPA with Hibernate 4.1 2.0 I need to hold two master / detail tables. My question if an exception in the detail , which do not store any data in the tables are presented.

Below shows my code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblmaster")
public class Master implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String mail;
    private List<Detail> listDetail = new ArrayList<Detail>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "secmaster", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "master", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Detail.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Detail> getListDetail() {
        return listDetail;
    }

    public void setListDetail(List<Detail> listaProgramaEducativo) {
        this.listDetail = listDetail;
    }

    public void addDetail(Detail detail) {
        listDetail.add(detail);
        detail.setDetail(this);
    }



@Entity
@Table(name = "tbldetail")
public class Detail implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;    
    private Master master;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "secdetail", nullable= false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "secmaster")
    public Master getMaster() {
        return master;
    }

    public void setMaster(Master master) {
        this.master = master;
    }   

Master master = new Master();
```

master.setMail("jj@gmail.com");

```
Detail detail1 = new Detail();
Detail detail2 = new Detail();

master.addDetail(detail1);
master.addDetail(detail2);
session.persist(master);
master.addDetail();
```

In the example I 'm working me an exception in detail by the size of the field . what I need is that if I create an exception in detail not keep in the master.

Answer (score 0):

Handling transactions depends on how you create transactions in your code.

If you begin and commit transactions imperatively in your code, then you should put whole transaction in a try..catch block, as described in [Hibernate Javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html):

```
 Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

If you use transactional beans (marked either with `@Transactional` annotation or EJBs), then any `RuntimeException` and some types of `PersistenceException` will cause transaction to be rolled back automatically